# Why is it "Día de las madres" but not "Día de madres"?

Tags: artículos

Related to ["Día de Muertos" or "El Día de los Muertos"?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/5804/d%c3%ada-de-muertos-or-el-d%c3%ada-de-los-muertos)

I understand when to use one or another but I can't articulate the reason.

For "Día de muertos" or "Fin de semana" we don't add "los" (Día de **los** muertos) or "la" (Fin de **la** semana), but we do add it for the mothers day "Día de las madres" (also I do understand what "Día de madres" would imply, "A rough day").

Just curious if someone can shed some light on how to explain it.

Comment: Actually, I've always heard "día de LOS muertos"...

Comment: In Chile we say "día de la madre", with singular noun.

Answer (score 1):

En algunas regiones del Caribe (Cuba y Puerto Rico) se usa la expresión *[de madre](https://www.asale.org/damer/madre)* con las siguientes acepciones:

> i.   loc. adj. Cu, PR. Referido a cosa o situación, tremenda, impresionante. pop.
> ii. Cu, PR. Referido a persona, inaguantable. pop.
> iii.    Cu. Referido a persona o cosa, muy mala. pop.

Si lo planteas como un *Día de madres* teniendo en cuenta esos significados, puede sonar ofensivo, como un día inaguantable o un día muy malo y no creo que eso es lo que busques al mencionar el Día de la madre

Answer (score 0):

Creo que solo es un error de interpretación y que son las mismas locuciones expresadas de manera diferente, prefiriendo simplemente utilizar unas u otras, según las zonas o países.

- Habitualmente no se dice "Día de las Madres" o "Día de Madres" para referirse al día de la Madre, sino simplemente "**Día de la Madre**" (Mother's Day) o "**El Día de la Madre**" , que es una festividad que se celebra en honor a **todas las madres** por lo que se sobrentiende que es "**El Día de** (todas) **las Madres**".

https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/D%C3%ADa_de_la_Madre

- Decir "El Día de los Muertos" o "Día de Muertos", ambos son correctos, y dependiendo del país donde vivas será más habitual decir una cosa u otra. En España por ejemplo no solemos decir "Día de los Muertos" o "Día de Muertos", sino "Día de los Santos", "Día de todos los Santos" o "Día de los Difuntos". Cuando se dice "Dia de Muertos", se esta sobrentendiendo que queremos decir "(El) **Día de** (los) **Muertos**"
- Para "**Fin de Semana**", según que contextos podemos decir sin problemas "El fin de la semana" pero hoy en día resulta obsoleto ya que se sobrentiende y resulta tedioso especificarlo, por lo que actualmente preferimos decir "**El Fin de Semana**" sobrentendiendo que nos estamos refiriendo y estamos diciendo (*el fin de la semana*, que actualmente es el Sábado y el Domingo, pero que antiguamente era solo el Domingo, pues el Sábado se trabajaba, quedando reducido el día de descanso solo al Domingo) o el más actual "**Finde**" en el que se sobrentiende igualmente que estamos queriendo decir (el **fin de** la semana), pero utilizando palabras intermedias, pues el idioma en general siempre tiende a economizar el lenguaje e intenta acortar palabras y sobrentender de manera implícita expresiones que habitualmente son más largas y que suelen utilizarse de manera frecuente.

**P.D.** No se si te habré aclarado alguna duda.

Answer (score 0):

"Fin de semana" is a set phrase like "fin de año".

As for "Día de la madre" or "Día de las madres", and irrespective of some local usage where a set phrase has been adopted, the use of the article is justified by the fact that the noun phrase with the article is the correct grammatical way to refer to a noun in a generic way in Spanish.

For example, we say:

- La madre es esencial para la crianza. (The mother is essential for upbringing.)
- Las madres son esenciales para la crianza. (Mothers are essential for upbringing.)

(In English, the plural with the zero article will be the most usual.)

Note: "Día de madres" can also be understood as a day when mothers have a day for themselves, free from their household duties.